# MySql2 and bundler on windows

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, mysql2

I know this question has been asked before, ive tried all the solutions and cant seem to get anywhere. Ive spent the better half of the day on this and im at my wits end.

I am trying to setup my app on a windows machine. Ive used the rails installer which comes with DevKit.

This works fine:

`gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-include=<PATH_TO_XAMPP>\mysql\include --with-mysql-lib=<PATH_TO_XAMPP>\mysql\lib\opt --with-mysql-config=<PATH_TO_XAMPP>\mysql\bin\mysql_config`

But `bundle install` fails with the native extension error.

Ive tried:

```
bundle config build.mysql --with-mysql-include=e:\xampp\xampp\mysql\include --with-mysql-lib=e:\xampp\xampp\mysql\lib\opt --with-mysql-config=e:\xampp\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql_config
```

But, no dice.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by using

`bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-include=e:\xampp\xampp\mysql\include --with-mysql-lib=e:\xampp\xampp\mysql\lib\opt --with-mysql-config=e:\xampp\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql_config`

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work now, but I'm finding that if you specify more than one flag for the config, bundler forgets it. Is there any way around that?